# Can one redirect too much data?

Tags: linux, pipe

I am working on a Linux system that runs on Kernel 3.2.0. On this system I wrote a program that in the end will generate roughly 50GB of data that it then would send to stdout. This output I want redirect to a file.

Can some kind of pipe overflow happen? Or do pipes work reliably regardless of the amount of data?

Comment: My concern would rather be how to handle a 50GB file...

Comment: Question already asked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715324/can-a-pipe-in-linux-ever-lose-data

Answer (score 6):

Pipes can't overflow. A pipe is just a buffer (a certain amount of memory, most likely 64KB on a current system) between a producer and a consumer. If the producer produces faster than the consumer consumes, the producer is *blocked* (that means, the program will sleep) until the consumer makes room in the buffer again by reading from it.

Besides, the case you describe isn't technically a pipe. If we're talking POSIX `sh`, redirection to a file (`acommand > afile`) makes the command's stdout point directly to the file. A pipe involves the `|` character, by coincidence also called "pipe", and is a connection between two running programs: `acommand | anothercommand`.

(But then again, what really happens behind the scenes is another story: For example, there are many pseudo device files under /dev which actually redirect to running processes. For instance, `echo Hello World > /dev/pts/1` may be writing to your current xterm)